# why datepart to extract hours is not working in case when?

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Hi all,`datepart`in`case when`didn't worked. I tried this...
>   This works:

`select status_name
        ,count(pk_lead_id) as leads 
where lm.lead_created_date between @sDate and @eDate
     and datepart(hh,lead_created_date) in (9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) 
     and datepart(hh,lead_created_date) in (20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
from lead_master group by status_name`

> But this doesn't give proper output:

`select status_name
        ,count(pk_lead_id) as leads --'9am to 8pm' and '8pm to 9am'
        ,count(case when cast(right(left(lead_created_date,13),2) as int) in (9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)then 1 else 0 end)as morning 
       ,count(case when cast(right(left(lead_created_date,13),2) as int) in (20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)then 1 else 0 end)as night
from lead_master group by status_name`

> I need query where`datepart`condition works in`case when`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you applying `RIGHT` and `LEFT` on a datetime column?

```
case when cast(right(left(lead_created_date,13),2) as int) in (9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)then 1 else 0 end
```

Change your query to:

```
select status_name
       ,count(pk_lead_id) as leads --'9am to 8pm' and '8pm to 9am'
       ,sum(case when datepart(hh,lead_created_date) in (9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19) then 1 else 0 end)as morning 
       ,sum(case when datepart(hh,lead_created_date) in (20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) then 1 else 0 end)as night
from lead_master group by status_name
```

Comment: friend, even that also I have tried. Case dosen't work like that. You can paste your own code in SQL and try it out.

Comment: your answer is not helping

Comment: My guess is you want sort of a COUNTIF function. If so, use SUM, not COUNT.